# Can Google Analytics compare the number of users who browsed different subdirectories?

Tags: google-analytics, subdirectory, visitors, google-data-studio

My website is composed of many shops. I would like to understand the amount of users browsing each shop.

Each shop has the following set of URLs:
`example.com/shop/shop-slug`
Each shop has category-page, attributes page, product pages, etc, which mean that there are a lot of subsequent URL to each shop. ie. `example.com/shop/shop-slug/XXXXX/YYYY`

What is the best way in Google Analytics to measure the number of users browsing each shop?
I would like to have a table having first column as shop-slug, second would be # users.
I would need to find a solution that is also applicable to Google Data Studio which is where my data will ultimately be used.

Last but not least, my users are often entering the shop by visiting first the `example.com` page so I can't use GA home page as a dimension.